# Deprecation warning in rails 2.3.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 2.3.11. I am getting a lot of deprecation warning like

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/delayed_job/tasks, 
vendor/plugins/fckeditor/tasks, 
vendor/plugins/jrails/tasks, 
vendor/plugins/query_reviewer/tasks, 
vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/tasks, 
vendor/plugins/tiny_mce/tasks, vendor/plugins/tolk/tasks,
 and vendor/plugins/xss_terminate/tasks are deprecated. 
Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
```

Give suggestions to avoid these warnings

Answer (score 0):

Move tasks into lib/tasks… 
No, actually, start using bundler. If an upgrade to Rails 3.x is too much work, at least move over to bundler and move all those dependencies into your Gemfile. It works fine with Rails 2.3.